# Efficiently get sum of sigmoid transformed differences between each value in two vectors using R/Rcpp

Tags: c++, r, performance, rcpp

My question is similar to: [R Subtract every element of vector A from every element of vector B](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29949764/r-subtract-every-element-of-vector-a-from-every-element-of-vector-b)

I have two vectors (vec1, vec2) of differing length containing values between 0 and 1. For each value in vec1 I need to find the difference from each value in vec2, do a sigmoid transform of the difference, then get the sum of these values corresponding to every value in both vectors. Using R I could do:

```
set.seed(0)
vec1=runif(5,0,1)
vec2=runif(10,0,1)

f=function(a,b){1/(1+exp(b-a))}
res=outer(vec1,vec2,f)
rowSums(res)
colSums(res)
```

However this gets slow for larger vectors (eg for lengths 2k and 50k this takes me around 7-8 sec). So I tried doing it using Rcpp which is a bit faster (5-6 sec):

```
require(Rcpp)
    Rcpp::cppFunction("
      Rcpp::List SFunc(NumericVector vec1, NumericVector vec2) {
        int n0=vec1.size(); 
        int n1=vec2.size();
        NumericVector z0(n0);
        NumericVector z1(n1);
        List out(2);

        for (int i=0; i<n1; ++i){
          for (int j=0; j<n0; ++j){
            double NewVal= 1/(1+exp(vec2[i]-vec1[j]));
            z0[j] = z0[j]+ NewVal;
            z1[i] = z1[i]+ NewVal;
          }
        }

        out[0]=z0; out[1]=z1;
        return out;
      }
    ")

res=SFunc(vec1,vec2)
```

Is there any way to speed this up further? A number of these calculations are already being done in parallel, so that is not a solution here.

Comment: Five seconds is not bad for 100 million combinations.

Comment: @Roland Yes, it is possible this is near the limit of what can be done. Perhaps there is some optimization I don't know about though.

Comment: In which case you would start by profiling for which you could use something like Google perftools.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Thanks for the tip. I'll try to figure that out.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel I didn't end up using any tool, but figured out that `1/(1+exp(-x)) ~ 0.5+0.2383*x` for the range of values I'm looking at. Substituting that calculation sped it up ~20x to to 0.25 s. This approximation may be close enough, I'm not sure yet. Thanks again.