# fast way in R to do two nested for loops

Tags: r, for-loop, optimization

I need to take the difference between any two elements of two vector.
If `A<-c(1,2)` and `B<-c(3,4)` then my result `R` should be `c(3-1,3-2,4-1,4-2)`.

With this snippet

```
myfunction <- function(N)
{
  A = runif(N)
  B = runif(N)
  R = c()
  for(a in A){
    for(b in B){
      R=c(b-a,R)
    }
  }
  R
}
print(system.time(result <- myfunction(300)))
```

I get this time

```
   user  system elapsed 
  14.27    0.01   14.39
```

Is there any faster way to do it?

Comment: `outer(A, B, `-`)` ? See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29950048/680068), quotes are getting messed up.

Comment: nice @zx8754, would not have thought that the baseR solution would be that fast!

Comment: @JanLauGe this is R, everything is a vector.

Comment: @zx8754 you're right about the duplicate, I missed that one.

Comment: @JorisMeys just waiting for OP to confirm before hammering.

Comment: @zx8754 too late, I hammered it :-) It is literally the exact same question, substraction and all.

Comment: @zx8754 Thank you for the duplicate. I would never find it!

Comment: Thank you to Google. But still a good question and effort.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fastest base solution is the use of `outer`:

```
as.vector(outer(B,A,"-"))
```

<strike>To my own surprise, `map2_dbl` is actually quite a bit faster than `outer`:</strike>

Not to my surprise, `map2_dbl` seems faster, but that's because it is not calculating *every combination* of values in A and B:

```
      test elapsed relative
3 CP(A, B)    7.54   47.125 # using expand.grid
2 JL(A, B)    0.16    1.000 # using map2_dbl
1 JM(A, B)    3.13   19.563 # using outer
```

But:

```
> A <- 1:3
> B <- 3:1
> JL(A,B)
[1] -2  0  2
> JM(A,B)
[1]  2  1  0  1  0 -1  0 -1 -2
```

This is for two vectors of length 1000, and with 100 replications. I didn't include your own solution because that one is ridiculously slow for two reasons:

- `for` loops in R are quite a bit faster than in the old days, but still not as optimal as using functions that have their loops coded in `C` or equivalent. That's the case for the functions used in the tested code here.
- you "grow" your result object. Every loop through the code, that `R` becomes one value larger, so R has to look for a new place in the memory to store it. That's actually the biggest bottleneck in your code. Try to avoid that kind of construct at all costs, because it's one of the most important causes of terribly slow code.

The benchmark code:

```
library(tidyverse)

JM <- function(A,B){
  as.vector(outer(B,A,"-"))
}

JL <- function(A,B){
  map2_dbl(.x = A, 
           .y = B, 
           .f = ~ c(.x - .y))
}

CP <- function(A,B){
  as.data.frame(expand.grid(A,B)) %>%
    mutate(Var3 = Var2-Var1)
}

library(rbenchmark)

A <- runif(1000)
B <- runif(1000)

benchmark(JM(A,B),
          JL(A,B),
          CP(A,B),
          replications = 100,
          columns = c("test","elapsed","relative"))
```

Comment: I tried `N = 100000` just now, at which point `outer` takes up too much memory on my machine (`Error: cannot allocate vector of size 74.5 Gb`). `map2_dbl` still works fine, in 0.14 seconds.

Comment: @zx8754 you have the code, you can smoke your own CPU if you're interested in that. I also figured out why `map2_dbl` is so fast: because it's not a solution to the problem :-)

Comment: Ah, makes sense why `map_dbl` is faster. Nice to know the `outer` solution.

Comment: @JorisMeys +1 thank you for your suggestions

Answer (score 2):

You can use `expand.grid` to vectorize the approach:

```
A <- runif(300)
B <- runif(300)

library(dplyr)
R <- as.data.frame(expand.grid(A,B)) %>%
       mutate(Var3 = Var2-Var1)
```

The first 5 lines of output:

```
      Var1     Var2          Var3
1 0.8516676 0.325261 -0.5264066246
2 0.2126453 0.325261  0.1126156694
3 0.5394620 0.325261 -0.2142010126
4 0.1364876 0.325261  0.1887734290
5 0.3248651 0.325261  0.0003958747
```

This took:

```
user  system elapsed 
0.02    0.00    0.02
```

Your function took:

```
 user  system elapsed 
42.39    0.43   42.90
```

Comment: `purrr::map2_dbl` is faster. Not that it matters on 300 values, but I am assuming the OP is looking to scale this up.

Comment: Umm...ok. First, you should show that you tested the difference in performance (compare it to my approach as well). Second, I know `purrr:map` is faster because I actually tested against my approach. Third, I gave you the only upvote you have at the moment. Fourth, we posted at the same time, which is why my post exists at all. Fifth, internet points aren't real, and you can't buy anything with them.

Comment: My comment seems to have upset you. That wasn't my intention, apologies. I like to think that I was merely interested in finding the best solution to the problem. I should have made that more clear.

Comment: Just edit your original answer next time. Follow @Joris Meys example

Answer (score -4):

Using `purrr::map2`:

```
library(tidyverse)

N = 300
A = runif(N)
B = runif(N)
R = c()

print(
  system.time(
    result <- map(
      .x = A,
      .f = ~ c(.x - B)) %>% unlist
  )
)
```

Time taken:

```
 user  system elapsed 
 0.02       0    0.02
```

If I got your attention now, check out [this repo](https://github.com/cwickham/purrr-tutorial) for a nice walk through of `purrr`.

Comment: Other options include the `apply` function family, but I like `purrr::map` as I think that it is a little bit more intuitive

Comment: Since this is about speed, and the other answers provide this too, would you mind adding a bit about the actual time it took to run this code compared to the OP's?

Comment: Obviously this is faster. It doesn't calculate all combinations, so it's not doing what OP asked. Try with `A <- 1:10` and `B <- 10:1` and you'll see.

Comment: Haha, you're right @Joris Meys, sorry about that!

Comment: Changed this to use `map`. Doing what it's supposed to do now?

Comment: @JanLauGe hmmm... now it looks as if you copy-pasted the code of Chi Pak in your answer. And in all honesty, I don't see how `map` would be a sensible solution here. It's a great function, but for a completely different purpose.

Comment: re 1) copy-paste error. re 2) fair enough, you're right :)  Thank you for spotting my mistake